# Using c# dynamic with embedded code in an aspx page

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

In my code behind I have a `public IEnumerable<dynamic> AllTransactions{ get; set; }` that is composed of `{Transaction, String}` (created via linq-to-sql as a new anonymous object) where `Transaction` is a custom class I have created.

In my aspx page I would like to do the following

```
<% foreach (dynamic trans in AllTransactions) { %>
    <span><%= trans.transaction.Amount %></span>
<% } %>
```

In my code behind I can refer to `trans.transaction.Amount` inside a `foreach` but I don't seem to have any luck on aspx pages. I get an exception:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'transaction'

At the same time, if I have the debugger running I can look at 'trans' and I see it has a Transaction object inside it called 'transaction' and it has my string as well.  Further, the 'transaction' object inside it contains a value for Amount. It seems that Microsoft is somewhere converting my dynamic to an object.

One other test I did was spit out what the type of trans is with GetType() and got this:

> <>f__AnonymousTypef`2[ProjectName.Packages.Investment.Business.Transaction,System.String]

This is not a regular 'object', so I'm not sure what the type of this is. Any ideas as to why my foreach doesn't work and what I can do differently?

Answer (score 2):

Try binding your data to a [repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) control. It was designed to output html for items in lists, and will help you separate your design from your logic, which is generally considered a much better practice than trying to dynamically generate html in script.

Comment: I appreciate the recommendation, but we do not use any ASP controls in our code. Unfortunately a decision was made here 9 years ago to only use MS tools, so we do use C# for our code behinds, but we completely manage our aspx pages via JQuery and standard HTML elements.

Comment: The repeater control is part of the .NET Framework, and fully supported by MS. Perhaps I am misreading your comment, but you can use many ASP controls without ever leaving the realm of Microsoft produced code. If It were my situation, I would try to update my company's policies to reflect the current technological environment in which you work. I will, however, take a second look at your question in the context you've given.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but we would rather not use any MS products if we can help it and we find we write better pages when we only have rudimentary CRUD logic in our code behinds, access public properties via embedded code in the aspx page, and manage all view-related systems via javascript. All you will find on our aspx pages is pure html 5. Microsoft may fully support a feature, but we would rather not depend on their implementation.

Comment: In that case, is it possible for you to create a struct for you to store your data in, instead of an anonymous type? Perhaps that would give you additional type safety.

Comment: That might be an idea, I'll try looking into it. I would prefer an anonymous type if possible. It would be nice if I could find some examples of anyone else trying to use dynamics with embedded code like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685218/cant-reference-dynamic-objects-in-embedded-aspx-code

Comment: In that question, the user uses the 'var' keyword in their foreach, instead of 'dynamic'... perhaps that is the cause of your problems?

Comment: No, I originally used var and then attempted to use dynamic instead, both causing the same exception. That other example isn't working either and he is basically doing the same thing I am.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this as below?

```
<% foreach (dynamic trans in AllTransactions) { %>
    <span><%= trans.Amount %></span>
<% } %>
```

Or can you check whether the definition of the custom class Transaction includes a member variable whose name is "Transaction"?

Comment: I had already tried your first suggestion using dynamic in my foreach but had the same trouble. My Transaction custom class does not include any variables or properties called "Transaction".